# Encryption prompts EOFException when trying to get customers with certain names

Tags: java, encryption

I'm working on a Intjellij project using restful dis and have implemented a very simple encryption that is implemented on both client and server side. One of the methods I invoke is getAllCustomers which works fine when I have customers with random names but will crash when I fx create a customer with a name like "Morten". It produces an "Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 451 path $[12]" on client side. The console on server side shows that the customers are sent over encrypted but when I debug the decrypting it doesn't seem to decrypt the entirety of the String.

Here is the Encryption class

```
 public class Encryption {

    public static String encryptDecrypt(String rawString) {


        char[] key = {'F', 'E', 'W', 'O', 'M','X','P'};


        StringBuilder thisIsEncrypted = new StringBuilder();


        for (int i = 0; i < rawString.length(); i++) {
            thisIsEncrypted.append((char) (rawString.charAt(i) ^ key[i % key.length]));
        }

        // We return the encrypted string
        return thisIsEncrypted.toString();
    }
}
```

Depending on what names I create the users with and what chars I use as keys it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

```
    public Trampoline<Void> getAllCustomers(){

    try
    {
        String url = BASE+"customers";

        String response = networkUtil.httpRequest(url, "GET");

        response = Encryption.encryptDecrypt(response);

        Customer[] customers = new Gson().fromJson(response, Customer[].class);


        return Trampoline.more(() -> view.ShowAllCustomers(Arrays.asList(customers)));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return Trampoline.more(()-> view.ShowMessage("Error getting customers from server. Message: " + e.getMessage()));
    }

}
```

Sometimes the error occurs in the end as mentioned above because it can't seem to get the final array bracket that is necessary [image]

And sometimes it seems to just not be able to decrypt the entire String, I am at a loss, does anyone have an idea of what the problem might be?

Comment: Does `response` contain what you expect after calling `httpRequest`? I mean, have you tried narrowing down exactly *where* something goes wrong?

Comment: That's what I tried to show in the screenshot, sorry if it was vaguely formulated. The respons contains the encrypted string. But the encrypted string seems to be lacking the final "]" when decrypted. Wether or not it is because it is never encrypted and sent from server in the first place, or lost during decryption I'm not sure of. 

But it shouldn't matter as the encryption class is identical on both client and server, so the problem would probably occur on both ends

Comment: `String` is not a container for binary data. Use `byte[]`.

Comment: @ProgrammingProdigy let me rephrase that: is the http response that is returning something weird or is the decryption that's broken? I doubt it's the second since it's symmetrical to the encryption, and if it is the first, well, you should check that, not the code you posted.

Comment: @ProgrammingProdigy also what user207421 said. You'll get weird characters with that encryption scheme, and the result is not fit for `String` and `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @ProgrammingProdigy `String` and `StringBuilder` are for strings made of printable characters. As soon as you start dealing with binary data (like your encrypted string) you're out of that realm. Since those two classes make certain assumption on the content of your strings, it's better to use raw bytes (so a `byte` array) to represent them.